# Python: How to make sorted skip/remove dictionaries without key?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key

Say I have the following array:

```py
pets = [
    {"owner": "Rick", "pet": "Fido"},
    {"owner": "Peter", "pet": "Hunter"},
    {"pet": "Dobbie"},
    {"owner": "Mason", "pet": "Tickles"},
]
```

**I am looking for a (most efficient) way to to remove `{"pet": "Dobbie"}` entirely from the list, while sorting it.**

if I were to do:

```py
sorted(pets, key=lambda k: k["owner"])
```

I would get an error saying that it didn't find the key in the third element.

If I were to do:

```py
sorted(pets, key=lambda k: k["owner"] if k.get("owner") else "ZZZ")
```

It would merely add it to the end of the list:

```py
[
    {"owner": "Mason", "pet": "Tickles"},
    {"owner": "Peter", "pet": "Hunter"},
    {"owner": "Rick", "pet": "Fido"},
    {"pet": "Dobbie"},
]
```

There is also a Plus/Alternative input:

```py
[
    {"owner": "Mason", "pet": "Tickles"},
    {"owner": "Peter", "pet": "Hunter"},
    {"owner": "Rick", "pet": "Fido"},
    {"owner": None, "pet": "Dobbie"},
]
```

Whereas it now has the key, but a null value. A solution for either this or the original input is equally valid for me.

Any pointers or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just filter then sort?

Comment: because that is looping through twice, which seems highly inefficient.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Sorting takes longer than filtering. If you filter (O(n)) this will leave you with fewer items to sort (O(n log n))

Comment: A sorting algorithm is not supposed to remove elements from the list; that is not its purpose. It also isn't able to sort a list with just one loop through it; the time taken to sort will dominate the time taken to filter.

Comment: In my case, it will be at least 0 items substracted, at most 1. So more towards maybe not.

Comment: Well, then sort and look to see if the last item needs to be removed. It all smells a bit of premature optimization to me.

Comment: That might work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generator expression to filter out, then use sorted with a lambda

```
>>> sorted((i for i in pets if 'owner' in i), key=lambda k:k['owner'])
[{'owner': 'Mason', 'pet': 'Tickles'},
 {'owner': 'Peter', 'pet': 'Hunter'},
 {'owner': 'Rick', 'pet': 'Fido'}]
```

Comment: This generator is just the same as using the `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dict.get` which you can supply a default return other than it's default `None`.

```
sorted(pets, key=lambda x: x.get('owner', 'ZZZ'))
```

Also `operator.methodcaller` is the more efficient way than using a `lambda`:

```
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> sorted(pets, key=methodcaller('get', 'owner', 'ZZZ'))
[{'owner': 'Mason', 'pet': 'Tickles'}, {'owner': 'Peter', 'pet': 'Hunter'}, {'owner': 'Rick', 'pet': 'Fido'}, {'pet': 'Dobbie'}]
```

You can also use `filter` to remove any `dicts` without an owner:

```
>>> get_owner = methodcaller('get', 'owner')
>>> sorted(filter(get_owner, pets), key=get_owner)
[{'owner': 'Mason', 'pet': 'Tickles'}, {'owner': 'Peter', 'pet': 'Hunter'}, {'owner': 'Rick', 'pet': 'Fido'}]
```